# Trying to do a CSS Transition on a class change

Tags: css

Was wondering if there was a way to do a css transition when div is given a certain class. My best example is this site http://ideaware.co/

When you scroll down and the header becomes fixed, it does a background color change and has opacity. Really nice looking.

I am working on a template I have here http://www.niviholdings.com/collide/ and what I want to do is when the < nav > becomes fixed, I want the < ul > to slide over to the right.

Hopefully I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: Fascinating! Your code seems perfectly right! I have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: It has to be my CSS then cause im getting the class to be added and it is margining-right, it's just not applying the transition.

Comment: I think it's the js, just don't know why. Chrome does the transition but with a repositioning before the animation. I think it may have something to do with the order you apply the classes.

Comment: It is in chrome now, FF seems to be the culprit. I will have to look at the order of my CSS I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

2 points i found that **may** help:

Transitions from `auto` to a fixed value might be a problem. Eventually you could try setting the `margin-left` of the `.main-nav-ul` to a fixed value per default, not only when it's sticky.

The second is (and this is hacky). Try to apply the class for your `.main-nav-ul` delayed:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.main-nav-ul').addClass('nav-slide'); // line 57 in jquery.sticky.js
}, 100);
```

Comment: Good call on the auto, it was jumpy in Chrome for sure, not using auto fixed that. Have to try the timeout still...

Comment: That did it, when I get enough rep I will upvote you all for helping :) the delay makes it work in FF.

Comment: why does the timeout do the trick? I mean it works!! But why? Shouldn't it work without a timeout?

Comment: It should. Why does it not? No idea, ask Mozilla or someone who is familiar with their rendering engine.

Answer (score 62):

> Was wondering if there was a way to do a css transition when div is
>   given a certain class.

Sure you can...

```js
document.querySelector('#header').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('transition');
})
```

```css
#header {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    left:0;
}

#header.transition {
    background: green;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Click me to toggle class</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQe7F/62/)

Comment: Can that be done without the click? Like when a < ul > is given a class? I basically just want my unordered list to margin right some pixels when it hits the top and becomes "sticky".

Comment: The click was just a way of adding a class. So yes, thats exactly what the example shows. How are you adding your class?

Comment: I was doing a .addClass inside the jquery.sticky.js that came with template. Just added it in the section where the actual position fixed takes place.

Comment: @3rror404 your demo doesn't transition the left property without adding left:0px to #header

Comment: 7 years old but still totally bodacious

Answer (score 11):

## CSS Transitions in 4 easy steps

1. Make sure that what you want to do is possible with CSS transitions. You can do that by [checking the W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css).
2. Add the transition, and your starting style, to your base element.
3. Add a class or state that has styles that have changed.
4. Add a mechanism to add the class (if applicable).

Quick example, let's say you want to animate a margin change on `:hover`. You'd just do this:

```
element {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: margin-left linear .5s;
}

element:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

[And here's a quick demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gordondev/eMGRk/)

Comment: That's using a pseudo class. In the example and my example its a header or a nav that I want the transition to be applied when it reaches a point (or sticks to the top). The first link in my example is doing it somehow.

Comment: @user2312618 - Very likely, it's JavaScript. Just set the JavaScript to add a class when a certain other event is triggered, such as when your header becomes fixed.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I think it's because it's the ul list I want to move but the < nav > is the thing that actually becomes sticky. (the unordered list is in the nav element).

Comment: Then post what you've tried, including code (not just a link to your site). Generic questions get generic answers. Take a little bit of time isolating the elements that are involved in what you're trying to do, that way we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I find it easy sometimes to inspect elements on the actual thing someone is working on. I realize not everyone does it that way. Next time I'll give more code upfront.

Comment: It's not just about how people prefer to do things, but also about the standards/expectations of StackOverflow. It's expected that a question (and answer) can "stand on its own", or not rely on an external site to be useful. If your site, or the one you linked, went down, your question would be left without any context and not be of use to anyone else. That said, your site looks really good so far. :)

Comment: @Shauna I usually follow those 4 steps, but I guess if you ONLY want a transition to happen when you add the class and NOT when you remove the class you could add the transition to the added class instead, right?
Or is that against anything?

Otherwise you would have to add another prop like visibility to achieve what you want:

```element {
  margin-left: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: margin-left linear .5s;
}

element:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
   visibility: visible;
}```

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you don't want to worry about which element the class is being applied, `@keyframe` animations are the solution.

```js
document.getElementById('circle')
.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('clicked')
})
```

```css
#circle {
  stroke: white;
  fill: green;
}

.clicked {
  animation: onClick 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes onClick {
  from {
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-width: 10px;
    fill: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-color: #2a2a2a;">
  <svg>
    <circle id="circle" cy="60" cx="60" r="50"/>
    <text
      x="60"
      y="60" 
      text-anchor="middle"
      stroke="white"
      pointer-events="none"
      fill="white"
      stroke-width="1px"
      alignment-baseline="middle"
    >
    Click Me
  </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This way, any element you apply the given class will animate, even if there is no css `transition` property applied.

Answer (score 0):

This will slide in an element from off screen (on the left) to on screen (on the right):

```
.element-to-slide {
  animation: slideMenuFromLeft 0.4s forwards;
} 
  
@keyframes slideMenuFromLeft {
  from {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  to {
    left:0;
  }
}
```